# different touch types on an UIImage will call different functions

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, events, uiimage, uicollectionview

I have a `CollectionView` with images in the cells. For the cells, or images in the cells, I want to implement 2 touch behaviors that call different functions.

1) a normal (short) tap on the UIImage will call the View with Details
2) a touch and hold on the UIImage will show a popup

Currently its not clear to me how to implement this best.

On the one hand I can try to use UIButton for that, meaning I have a UIButton with an Image. Then I could use for the option 1) `Touch up inside` and for option 2) `Touch down`. 
But in my head it's saying a `Touch down` is done in both case, how do ios know that is a short tap and not a touch and hold... Do I have to help the system to distinguish it?
Beside that, I sounds strange to have all Images (which can be a lot) as UIButtons. Is it possible to assign 2 touches to UIButton?

On the other hand I could stay at UIImage and use  `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, and `touchesEnded`. And write function which checks the time spend for the touch... Here I think its possible to call two different functions.

For both: Does this interfere with the scrolling behavior of the CollectionView? As Scrolling is a *touch and hold and drag*...?

[Touch events reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIControl_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Control_Events)

Any ideas?

Cheers -- jerik

Answer (score 0):

This is a good application of UIGestureRecognizer, specifically, `UITapGestureRecognizer` and `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`.  Both can be attached to either each image or each cell.  When attaching to the image, be sure to set it's `userInteractionEnabled` property = YES.

Also remember that collection view cells are reused, so you should check the count of the view's gestureRecognizers array before adding any.

Distinguishing between a touch down that's the start of a tap and a touch down that's the start of a long press isn't a job for software - that's fortune telling.  The only alternative  - no matter the software - is to recognize the tap on the release (when `state == UIGestureRecognizerStateRecognized`).

The two competing gestures should interact by using `requireGestureRecognizerToFail:`.  See the [reference here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html).